# CIDR block information is for Salesforce

Tags: security

I do not find related questions here, so can someone help to understand CIDR block information is for Salesforce related to pricing loader? Pricing loader is a custom build functionality in org, button click will get client hotel details like room availability, price and all from the other system.

where can I find IP ranges configured for the Pricing loader?. 
I can see few IP addresses in Network access, but how can I say these are whitelisted for the rateloader?.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides this information in the Knowledge article [What are the Salesforce IP Addresses & Domains to whitelist?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1). I'm not going to include the details here because it's updated regularly and the list of IP blocks is very long.

Outbound connections made by your custom functionality on-platform will come from somewhere within the Salesforce pool of IP ranges, but as noted in the linked document,

> Salesforce does not offer static IP addresses or small ranges of IP addresses for individual instances.

Hence, there is no specific IP block for your custom functionality beyond the full suite of Salesforce ranges.

Comment: Thanks@David and is this something like whitelisted addresses in network access in security settings? .

Comment: Yes, but for whitelists on external written receiving connections from Salesforce.